# Angular ng2-daterangepicker package customization issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular and i faced a problem. I tried to create two more fields to choose date range value. One for the start and one for the end. I did this and it even works, but.. not really. The point is that my input value ( main input ) falls back to the default value that i specify in the options object as the field loses focus ( at least i think so ).
Here is my daterange-input.component.ts file:

```
import {
  Component,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  forwardRef,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Renderer2,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from "@angular/forms";
import * as moment from "moment";
import {ValidationService} from "../../../services/validation/validation.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-daterange-input',
  templateUrl: './daterange-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./daterange-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DaterangeInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class DaterangeInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  @Input() options: any;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() coverClass: string;
  @Input() labelClass: string;
  @Input() inputClass: string;
  @Input() labelText: string;
  @Input() inputDivCover: string;
  @Input() control: AbstractControl | null;

  selectedDateRange: any;
  dateFormat: string;

  // Add a new property to track whether to show additional fields or not
  created: boolean;
  startInputValue: string | null = null;
  endInputValue: string | null = null;

  private onChange: (value: any) => void = () => {
  };
  private onTouched: () => void = () => {
  };

  constructor(public validationService:ValidationService,
              private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.created = false;
    this.dateFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    this.name = "";
    this.coverClass = "form-inline";
    this.labelClass = "";
    this.inputClass = "form-control-styled form-control";
    this.labelText = "";
    this.inputDivCover = "";
    this.control = null;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.options.startDate && this.options.endDate) {
      this.updateValueCover(this.options.startDate, this.options.endDate)
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', this.onDocumentClick.bind(this));

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to remove the event listener when the component is destroyed
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.onDocumentClick.bind(this));
  }

  onDocumentClick(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    const isDaterangepickerInput = target.matches('#' + this.name) || target.parentElement?.matches('#' + this.name);

    if (isDaterangepickerInput && !this.created) {
      this.created = true;
      console.log("fdfdf")
      this.createAdditionalElements();
    }
  }

  updateValueCover(start: any, end: any) {
    const startDate = moment(start, this.dateFormat);
    const endDate = moment(end, this.dateFormat);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectedDateRange = {start: startDate, end: endDate};
      console.log(this.selectedDateRange)
      if (this.onChange) {
        this.onChange(this.formatDateRange(this.selectedDateRange));
      }
      if (this.onTouched) {
        this.onTouched();
      }
    });
  }

  createAdditionalElements() {
    // Create the left calendar container and input element
    const leftCalendarDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.addClass(leftCalendarDiv, 'drp-calendar');
    this.renderer.addClass(leftCalendarDiv, 'left');
    const leftInput = this.renderer.createElement('input');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(leftInput, 'type', 'text');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(leftInput, 'name', this.name + '-start');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(leftInput, 'id', this.name + '-start');
    this.renderer.listen(leftInput, 'change', (event: Event) => this.onStartDateChange((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
    this.renderer.setProperty(leftInput, 'value', this.selectedDateRange?.start?.format(this.dateFormat));
    this.renderer.appendChild(leftCalendarDiv, leftInput); // Append the input element inside the div container

    // Create the right calendar container and input element
    const rightCalendarDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.addClass(rightCalendarDiv, 'drp-calendar');
    this.renderer.addClass(rightCalendarDiv, 'right');
    const rightInput = this.renderer.createElement('input');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(rightInput, 'type', 'text');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(rightInput, 'name', this.name + '-end');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(rightInput, 'id', this.name + '-end');
    this.renderer.listen(rightInput, 'change', (event: Event) => this.onEndDateChange((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
    this.renderer.setProperty(rightInput, 'value', this.selectedDateRange?.end?.format(this.dateFormat));
    this.renderer.appendChild(rightCalendarDiv, rightInput); // Append the input element inside the div container

    this.renderer.addClass(leftInput, "form-control-styled");
    this.renderer.addClass(rightInput, "form-control-styled");

    const calendarLeftElement = document.body.querySelector('.drp-calendar.left');
    const calendarRightElement = document.body.querySelector('.drp-calendar.right');

    this.renderer.appendChild(calendarLeftElement, leftCalendarDiv);
    this.renderer.appendChild(calendarRightElement, rightCalendarDiv);
  }

  onStartDateChange(value: string) {
    this.startInputValue = value;
    this.updateDateRange();
  }

  onEndDateChange(value: string) {
    this.endInputValue = value;
    this.updateDateRange();
  }

  updateDateRange() {
    // If both start and end date inputs have values, update the selectedDateRange
    if (this.startInputValue && this.endInputValue) {
      this.updateValueCover(this.startInputValue, this.endInputValue)
      this.writeValue({start: this.startInputValue, end:this.endInputValue})
    }
  }

  get controlElement() {
    return this.control;
  }

  onDateSelected(dateRange: any) {
    this.selectedDateRange = this.formatDateRange(dateRange);
    if (this.onChange) {
      this.onChange(this.formatDateRange(dateRange));
    }
    if (this.onTouched) {
      this.onTouched();
    }
  }

  formatDateRange(dateRange: any): string {
    if (dateRange?.start && dateRange?.end) {
      const startFormatted = dateRange.start.format(this.dateFormat);
      const endFormatted = dateRange.end.format(this.dateFormat);
      return this.options.singleDatePicker ? `${startFormatted}` : `${startFormatted} - ${endFormatted}`;
    }
    return dateRange;
  }

  updateValue(value: any) {
    this.selectedDateRange = this.formatDateRange(value);

    if (this.onChange) {
      this.onChange(this.formatDateRange(value));
    }
    if (this.onTouched) {
      this.onTouched();
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value && value.start && value.end) {
      this.selectedDateRange = {
        start: moment(value.start, this.dateFormat),
        end: moment(value.end, this.dateFormat)
      };
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.onChange) {
          this.onChange(this.formatDateRange(this.selectedDateRange));
        }
        if (this.onTouched) {
          this.onTouched();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    // You can handle disabling the input here if needed
  }

  onBlurSelected() {
    if (!this.selectedDateRange) {
      this.onDateSelected({
        start: moment(),
        end: moment(),
        label: null
      })
    }
  }
}
```

and my daterange-input.component.html:

```
<div class="{{coverClass}}">
  <label class="{{labelClass}}" [htmlFor]="name">{{labelText}}</label>
  <div class="{{inputDivCover}}">
    <input
      type="text"
      [name]="name"
      [id]="name"
      daterangepicker
      class="{{inputClass}}"
      [options]="options"
      (selected)="onDateSelected($event)"
      (blur)="onBlurSelected()"
      [ngClass]="{'single-datepicker': options.singleDatePicker}"
      [ngModel]="formatDateRange(selectedDateRange)"
      [class.ng-invalid]="!validationService.isValid(controlElement)"
      [class.ng-valid]="validationService.isValid(controlElement)"
      [class.ng-touched]="controlElement!.touched"
      (ngModelChange)="updateValue($event)">
  </div>
  <error-field [fieldToValidate]="{meta:controlElement, name:name}"></error-field>
</div>
```

.
How i use this component in the code:

```
 <div class="col-33 pr-lg">
                <app-daterange-input
                  [options]="dateRangeProps"
                  formControlName="poDate"
                  [control]="filters.get('poDate')"
                  [labelText]="'PO Submit Date'"
                  [labelClass]="'flex-basis-100 w-50-i margin-unset'"
                  [inputDivCover]="'date wr-datepicker w-50-i'"
                  [name]="'poDate'"
                ></app-daterange-input>
              </div>
```

my filters formGroup:

```
 this.filters = new FormGroup({
      client: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      contract: new FormControl({value:"", disabled: true}, [Validators.required]),
      poDate: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
})
```

and my dateRangeProps:

```
{
    "showDropdowns": true,
    "ranges": {
        "Today": [
            "2023-07-21T17:29:19.967Z",
            "2023-07-21T17:29:19.967Z"
        ],
        "Yesterday": [
            "2023-07-20T17:29:19.967Z",
            "2023-07-20T17:29:19.968Z"
        ],
        "This Week": [
            "2023-07-15T21:00:00.000Z",
            "2023-07-22T20:59:59.999Z"
        ],
        "Last Week": [
            "2023-07-08T21:00:00.000Z",
            "2023-07-15T20:59:59.999Z"
        ],
        "Last 7 Days": [
            "2023-07-15T17:29:19.969Z",
            "2023-07-21T17:29:19.969Z"
        ],
        "Last 30 Days": [
            "2023-06-22T17:29:19.969Z",
            "2023-07-21T17:29:19.969Z"
        ],
        "This Month": [
            "2023-06-30T21:00:00.000Z",
            "2023-07-31T20:59:59.999Z"
        ],
        "Last Month": [
            "2023-05-31T21:00:00.000Z",
            "2023-06-30T20:59:59.999Z"
        ],
        "This Year": [
            "2022-12-31T22:00:00.000Z",
            "2023-12-31T21:59:59.999Z"
        ],
        "All": [
            "1899-12-31T21:57:56.000Z",
            "2500-12-30T22:00:00.000Z"
        ]
    },
    "showCustomRangeLabel": true,
    "alwaysShowCalendars": true,
    "autoApply": true,
    "startDate": "07/10/2023",
    "endDate": "07/15/2023",
    "singleDatePicker": false
}
```

In fact i need it not to drop the value that i input in those inputs and it must update the value in real time ( during printing )

The issue seems to be related to the behavior of the daterangepicker library and how it handles updates from the underlying ngModel binding. When the input field loses focus, the daterangepicker library might be resetting the input value based on the options provided. But also i think that it is possibly that the issue is related to the synchronization between the visible input and the underlying selectedDateRange value. This happens because the ngModel directive updates the visible value of the input based on the selectedDateRange, but it doesn't automatically update the selectedDateRange when the input value changes. I tried to play with ngModel and selectedDateRange but it all was useless. Value is seen in the formGroup ( new value ) but still i see the old value on the UI

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer my question in case you need to do the same. I cleaned up the code and check the documentation. Here is the solution:

```js
 import {
      Component,
      ComponentFactoryResolver,
      forwardRef,
      Input,
      OnInit,
      Renderer2, ViewChild,
      ViewContainerRef
    } from '@angular/core';
    import {AbstractControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from "@angular/forms";
    import * as moment from "moment";
    import {ValidationService} from "../../../services/validation/validation.service";
    import { DaterangepickerComponent } from 'ng2-daterangepicker';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-daterange-input',
      templateUrl: './daterange-input.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./daterange-input.component.scss'],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => DaterangeInputComponent),
          multi: true
        }
      ]
    })
    
    export class DaterangeInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
      @Input() options: any;
      @Input() name: string;
      @Input() coverClass: string;
      @Input() labelClass: string;
      @Input() inputClass: string;
      @Input() labelText: string;
      @Input() inputDivCover: string;
      @Input() control: AbstractControl | null;
      @ViewChild(DaterangepickerComponent) private picker: DaterangepickerComponent | undefined;
    
      selectedDateRange: any;
      dateFormat: string;
    
      // Add a new property to track whether to show additional fields or not
      created: boolean;
      startInputValue: string | null = null;
      endInputValue: string | null = null;
    
      private onChange: (value: any) => void = () => {
      };
      private onTouched: () => void = () => {
      };
    
      constructor(public validationService:ValidationService,
                  private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
                  private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
                  private renderer: Renderer2) {
        this.created = false;
        this.dateFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        this.name = "";
        this.coverClass = "form-inline";
        this.labelClass = "";
        this.inputClass = "form-control-styled form-control";
        this.labelText = "";
        this.inputDivCover = "";
        this.control = null;
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        if (this.options.startDate && this.options.endDate) {
          this.updateValueCover(this.options.startDate, this.options.endDate)
        }
        document.addEventListener('click', this.onDocumentClick.bind(this));}
    
      ngOnDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to remove the event listener when the component is destroyed
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.onDocumentClick.bind(this));
      }
    
      onDocumentClick(event: Event) {
        console.log("6")
        const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
        const isDaterangepickerInput = target.matches('#' + this.name) || target.parentElement?.matches('#' + this.name);
    
        if (isDaterangepickerInput && !this.created) {
          this.created = true;
          this.createAdditionalElements();
        }
      }
    
      updateValueCover(start: any, end: any) {
        console.log("5")
        const startDate = moment(start, this.dateFormat);
        const endDate = moment(end, this.dateFormat);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.selectedDateRange = {start: startDate, end: endDate};
          console.log(this.selectedDateRange)
          if (this.onChange) {
            this.onChange(this.formatDateRange(this.selectedDateRange));
          }
          if (this.onTouched) {
            this.onTouched();
          }
        });
      }
    
      createAdditionalElements() {
        // Create the left calendar container and input element
        const leftCalendarDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div');
        this.renderer.addClass(leftCalendarDiv, 'drp-calendar');
        this.renderer.addClass(leftCalendarDiv, 'left');
        const leftInput = this.renderer.createElement('input');
        this.renderer.setAttribute(leftInput, 'type', 'text');
        this.renderer.setAttribute(leftInput, 'name', this.name + '-start');
        this.renderer.setAttribute(leftInput, 'id', this.name + '-start');
        this.renderer.listen(leftInput, 'change', (event: Event) => this.onStartDateChange((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
        this.renderer.setProperty(leftInput, 'value', this.selectedDateRange?.start?.format(this.dateFormat));
        this.renderer.appendChild(leftCalendarDiv, leftInput); // Append the input element inside the div container
    
        // Create the right calendar container and input element
        const rightCalendarDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div');
        this.renderer.addClass(rightCalendarDiv, 'drp-calendar');
        this.renderer.addClass(rightCalendarDiv, 'right');
        const rightInput = this.renderer.createElement('input');
        this.renderer.setAttribute(rightInput, 'type', 'text');
        this.renderer.setAttribute(rightInput, 'name', this.name + '-end');
        this.renderer.setAttribute(rightInput, 'id', this.name + '-end');
        this.renderer.listen(rightInput, 'change', (event: Event) => this.onEndDateChange((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
        this.renderer.setProperty(rightInput, 'value', this.selectedDateRange?.end?.format(this.dateFormat));
        this.renderer.appendChild(rightCalendarDiv, rightInput); // Append the input element inside the div container
    
        this.renderer.addClass(leftInput, "form-control-styled");
        this.renderer.addClass(rightInput, "form-control-styled");
    
        const calendarLeftElement = document.body.querySelector('.drp-calendar.left');
        const calendarRightElement = document.body.querySelector('.drp-calendar.right');
    
        this.renderer.appendChild(calendarLeftElement, leftCalendarDiv);
        this.renderer.appendChild(calendarRightElement, rightCalendarDiv);
      }
    
      onStartDateChange(value: string) {
        this.startInputValue = value;
        this.updateDateRange();
      }
    
      onEndDateChange(value: string) {
        this.endInputValue = value;
        this.updateDateRange();
      }
    
      updateDateRange() {
        console.log("4")
        // If both start and end date inputs have values, update the selectedDateRange
        if (this.startInputValue && this.endInputValue) {
          this.updateValueCover(this.startInputValue, this.endInputValue)
          if(this.picker) {
            this.picker.datePicker.setStartDate(this.startInputValue);
            this.picker.datePicker.setEndDate(this.endInputValue);
          }
        }
      }
    
      get controlElement() {
        return this.control;
      }
    
      onDateSelected(dateRange: any) {
        console.log("3")
        this.selectedDateRange = this.formatDateRange(dateRange);
        if (this.onChange) {
          this.onChange(this.selectedDateRange);
        }
        if (this.onTouched) {
          this.onTouched();
        }
      }
    
      formatDateRange(dateRange: any): string {
        console.log("2", dateRange)
        if (dateRange?.start && dateRange?.end) {
          const startFormatted = dateRange.start.format(this.dateFormat);
          const endFormatted = dateRange.end.format(this.dateFormat);
          return this.options.singleDatePicker ? `${startFormatted}` : `${startFormatted} - ${endFormatted}`;
        }
    
        return dateRange;
      }
    
      writeValue(value: any): void {
        if (value && value.start && value.end) {
          this.selectedDateRange = {
            start: moment(value.start, this.dateFormat),
            end: moment(value.end, this.dateFormat)
          };
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.onChange) {
              this.onChange(this.formatDateRange(this.selectedDateRange));
            }
            if (this.onTouched) {
              this.onTouched();
            }
          });
        }
      }
    
      registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
      }
    
      registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
      }
    
      setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        // You can handle disabling the input here if needed
      }
    
      onBlurSelected() {
        if (!this.selectedDateRange) {
          this.onDateSelected({
            start: moment(),
            end: moment(),
            label: null
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

Go here for more details: [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-daterangepicker#daterangepicker-methods)
And html:

```html
<div class="{{coverClass}}">
  <label class="{{labelClass}}" [htmlFor]="name">{{labelText}}</label>
  <div class="{{inputDivCover}}">
    <input
      type="text"
      [name]="name"
      [id]="name"
      daterangepicker
      class="{{inputClass}}"
      [options]="options"
      (blur)="onBlurSelected()"
      [ngClass]="{'single-datepicker': options.singleDatePicker}"
      [ngModel]="formatDateRange(selectedDateRange)"
      [class.ng-invalid]="!validationService.isValid(controlElement)"
      [class.ng-valid]="validationService.isValid(controlElement)"
      [class.ng-touched]="controlElement!.touched">
  </div>
  <error-field [fieldToValidate]="{meta:controlElement, name:name}"></error-field>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).